# using OR on mysql JOINs

Tags: mysql, join

Is there a way to specify a mysql query that does something like this

```
SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON (a.xyz = b.xyz OR a.xyr = b.xyr);
```

and therefore returns rows when any of the LEFT JOIN criteria on the ON statement matches up...

if so what would be the syntax of such queries?

Comment: With the LEFT JOIN, you get data even when no row in `b` matches the current row in `a`.  You probably only need JOIN.  And, as noted, you can perfectly well use the syntax you showed.  Sometimes, it is quicker to try these things than to ask questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the select statement into two parts and use a UNION.

```
SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b on a.xyz = b.xyz
UNION
SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b on a.xyr = b.xyr
```

If the UNION in MySQL is like the UNION in SQL Server, it should produce a set without duplicate rows.  Otherwise, you may need to use a DISTINCT.

Comment: but what if you want to put a WHERE, GROUP BY, SUM, etc on the entire thing? how would you do it so that both are affected

Comment: wrap the whole entire union statement into a subquery and apply the statements necessary after that.  depending on the desired results, the WHERE and aggregate statemetns can be used even at the individual select levels prior UNIONing.

Answer (score 1):

According the the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) the `ON` clause is a *conditional expression*. So **yes**, you can use such an expression. In fact, exactly what you have should work.

However, depending on your data and join type, it could produce some *unintuitive* results.